# About morphisms (regular maps) bewtween quasi-projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I don't understand a passage in the definition of  morphism (called also regular map) between quasi projective varieties. To get a complete definition one can perform three steps which are listed below, but I have problems to understand the step $3$. All the following definitions/notations are taken from Shafarevich's books.

---

**Step 1. Definition of regular function:**
[image]

---

**Step 2. Definition of morphism/regular map**:
[image]

---

Now the author seems to want to give a second definition after a brief discussion:

---

**Step 3. Second definition of morphism/regular map**:
[image]

---

And finally my doubt: in the definition included in the step 3, I don't understand why it is necessary to suppose that $X$ is irreducible. In the preamble, it seems that this assumption is not necessary. If $X$ is not irreducible, is the second definition wrong?

**Addendum:** Is it false that every morphism can be espressed as the second definition? I don't see the equivalence of the two definitions.

Comment: It's the matter of simplification I think. So knowing the second definition, you can now define a regular map from a *reducible* quasi-projective variety to $\mathbb{P}^m,$ right?

Comment: So in the second definition $X$ can be a generic quasi-projective variety. However the point is that, if don't exist the functions $F_0,\ldots, F_m$ such that for some $i$ $F_i\neq 0$ in $X$, we can't express a morphism in the "second way". I'm right?